# Bitbucket unable to push in team repo (authentication failed)

Tags: git, authentication, bitbucket

When I create a repo in my individual account of Bitbucket, I am able to push anything I want. So, my SSH key is correctly registered in Bitbucket.

But when one my teams (which I am an administrator) creates a repo, I cant push anymore. When I try that, I receive "Authentication failed".

What am I missing?

thanks for the help!

Comment: Ps: I realize that it's occurs only when I init a local git repo (git init), add a remote origin (git add remote origin ...).
If I clone the repo, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably occurred because some instability in the environment bitbucket if the error still persists, I believe it is the configuration of the ssh key, I had the same problem, but after an update everything is working again perfectly.

If not resolved, send email to support@bitbucket.org and mention this issue.

Look that exemple:

https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/7803/getting-500-internal-server-error-since

Comment: It is a habit to describe shortly what is the link about. The answer should work even if the link is broken.